# How to display multiple checkboxes into textView in another activity

Tags: android, checkbox

This code only manage to display only one checkbox's text on the textview on the another activity. I really appreciate if somebody could help me with this. P/S: I am a newbie.

This is my current code on MainActivity:

```
package com.example.ujianrisiko;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//protected static final String selectedItemData = null;
Button button1;
CheckBox checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3, checkBox4, checkBox5, checkBox6, checkBox7, checkBox8, checkBox9, checkBox10, checkBox11, checkBox12, checkBox13, checkBox14, checkBox15, checkBox16, checkBox17;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#E71E67")));

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    checkBox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
    checkBox4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
    checkBox5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
    checkBox6 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);
    checkBox7 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox7);
    checkBox8 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox8);
    checkBox9 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox9);
    checkBox10 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox10);
    checkBox11 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox11);
    checkBox12 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox12);
    checkBox13 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox13);
    checkBox14 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox14);
    checkBox15 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox15);
    checkBox16 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox16);
    checkBox17 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox17);


        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Start email activity using explicit intent
            //new Intent (From where, To where);

            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AdviceActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("selected", checkBox1.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });


}
```

}

And here is my code another activity:

```
package com.example.ujianrisiko;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AdviceActivity extends Activity {

TextView textView1, textView2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_advice);


    textView1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    //Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    //String selection = b.getString("selection");
    String selecteditem=getIntent().getExtras().getString("selected");
    textView2.setText(selecteditem);

}
```

}

Comment: what you want to do????  you want all data that are checked to be displayed in next activity. Is that it!

Comment: Add OnCheckedChangeListener or OnClickListener For Checkbox. Based on Checked State Add to ArrayList or Hashmap. Then Pass It To Another Activity and get from same in another to display it in textView

Comment: like this, I want to create a form containing multiple checkboxes. I want user to be able to select more than 1 checkbox, then when a button is click, another activity will show up displaying all the value in the checkbox that is selected before.

Comment: could you show me the code. I'm not really familiar with arrayList or Hashmap. Thanks

Comment: Have you Checked the Answer

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use `StringBuilder` to store all checkbox values like this way

```
 public static final String SEPERATOR = ",";
 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 stringBuilder.append(checkBox1.getText().toString());
 stringBuilder.append(SEPERATOR + checkBox2.getText().toString());
 stringBuilder.append(SEPERATOR + checkBox3.getText().toString());
 ...
```

and send your data

```
 Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AdviceActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("selected", stringBuilder.toString());
 startActivity(i);
```

Then you have to split the data and store it in a `String Array`.

```
String[] datas = getIntent().getExtras().getString("selected").split(SEPERATOR);
```

Here in `datas` you can get all the values.

Comment: Where should I put the code                                                            
 public static final String SEPERATOR = ",";
 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 stringBuilder.append(checkBox1.getText().toString());
 stringBuilder.append(SEPERATOR + checkBox2.getText().toString());
 stringBuilder.append(SEPERATOR + checkBox3.getText().toString());
 ...

Comment: Declare public static final String SEPERATOR = "," as a global variable(Where you declare button1). And other code inside onclick. Let me know if you face any other problem.

Comment: where should i put this? String[] datas = line.split(SEPERATOR);

Comment: String selecteditem=getIntent().getExtras().getString("selected"); instead of this line use this one  String[] datas = getIntent().getExtras().getString("selected").split(SEPERATOR);

Comment: how about this code. i still don't know where should i put this: String[] datas = line.split(SEPERATOR)

Comment: oh so you mean put the code at the other activity. Then how can i displayed the data in the textview. I got error when i wrote it like this: String[] datas = getIntent().getExtras().getString("selected").split(SEPERATOR);
  textView2.setText(datas);

Comment: for textView1 you can get the value like this datas[1] so textView1.setText(datas[1]), textView2.setText(datas[2]) and so on.

Comment: already did everything sir, still not working. Even though I didn't select any checkbox, the textview is displaying data from the second checkbox

Comment: It is showing data because you are passing checkbox text.